# How to check that some string contains a substring in the unit test code?

Tags: unit-tests

Dear Developers and QA,

I would like to ask a very simple question, but it is very important for me.

Please, consider the following test:

> When I enter the search phrase “Hello World” into the Google Search
>   box Then the Google’s search page title should contain the string
>   “Hello World”

How would you implement this verification (assertion) in the unit test code? 
Please, post your code samples in **any** programming languages you like.

Thanks in advance,
Dmitry

Comment: There are a lot of ways to implement this, from directly calling the page using HttpWebRequest to using an automation framework like Selenium to mimic user interaction on the site itself.  Your question is very open ended and generic and doesn't really give a lot of details about what you are trying to accomplish.  More details would be great.  What is the point of this exercise?

Comment: Hi Sam, 
I need some statistics on how the developers and automated testers are implementing this case. 
It is not about any technical details, so, for instance, you already have a variable 
expectedSubstring = “Hello World” and actualTitle = “hello world – Google Search”.

Answer (score 2):

I find it hard to believe that this is a unit test (unit being single function/method).

This seems more like a basic functional test through the user interface.

As Sam says there are many ways this can be done and different levels to "intercept" or get the "result."

WRT language, C# and Java have a method called string.Contains, and C++ has string.find. I am sure other languages have similar methods.